# Command Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO via bash Windows 10

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, rpi.gpio, windows

```
from RPi import GPIO
global ON
global OFF
OFF = GPIO.LOW
ON = GPIO.HIGH
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
x = open(testo.txt")
if x.read() == "true":
    GPIO.output(21, ON)
else:
    GPIO.output(21, OFF)
```

I need to set high/low an output of my raspberry pi 4 from windows .bat file.
Inside the .bat file I create a text file containing either true or false.
If the text is true the output goes high, if it is false it goes low.

My program reads the contents of the file but the IF doesn't work; it read only the content of the ELSE, even if the text file contains true.
do you know why?

Comment: Are you running Windows on the Pi?  If you are using Raspberry Pi OS why not just use a Linux batch file.  Why do you mention Windows?

Comment: i have a windows pc where i start the batch file.
the batch file create the file txt and send it to raspberry pi.

Comment: The file is nonsense and would generate error messages. Why don't you fix them?

Comment: @Milliways where is the error, can you help me?
it's my first time with raspberry pi...

Comment: There are errors in the Python as presented.  Why not use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)?  You could then run a Python script on the Windows machine to control the Pi GPIO.

Comment: @joan how it function pigpio?

Comment: open(testo.txt") and it is far from clear what x.read() would produce. As you have posted no output of attempting to run your program who knows? This looks like a programming question - nothing specific to Pi.

Comment: The row, `x = open(testo.txt")` is missing a **"**. It should look like this `x = open("testo.txt")`